# insist him on vs insist on him

Tags: word-usage

> She insists him on early attendance.

This sentence sounds odd to me.

Shouldn't it be either

> She insists on him that he arrives early.

OR

> She insists on him an early attendance.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your examples is correct.
We don't **insist on somebody** but we can insist **on** somebody's arrival/attendance etc or we can **insist that* somebody should do something.

So, possible options are:

> She insisted that he (should) arrive early.
> She insisted on his early arrival.

You will find examples of the construction: **S/he insisted to....somebody** but they are few and far between and many people might query their use.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/insist
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insist

Comment: I understand what you have said here. I checked out the oxford link you have shared. It also says, the following: 

**insist on something/somebody doing something (formal)
She insisted on his/him wearing a suit.**

So, it appears like both his and him can be used along with "insist on"
Going by this, is it okay to say, "She insists on him arriving early" ?

Comment: You will find both forms in everyday English, and not only after insist. **Him** is now often used where **his** was used before, as in: **I don't like his seeing that boy**. (**His** is a possessive pronoun treating **seeing** as a gerund.) These days you more often hear **I don't like him seeing that boy**. The same problem doesn't arise with her because it doubles as both a possessive pronoun ((her dog) and a personal pronoun (I like her).